# css menu breaks after space

Tags: css, css-float

i have a problem. please check the below link
[My site](http://dnanetworks.com.preview.gearhost.com/)

in my second menu "ABOUT DNA" is not properly showing, the word DNA must come in line with ABOUT.

here is my css

```
#menu-home li{float: left;padding:13px 2%;}
    #menu-home>li>a{ text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; font-family:arial; font-size:16px; font-weight:500;  padding:13px 2%; }
```

i am using wordpress and wp_nav_menu produces html
where i did wrong???

Comment: It is in 1 line when I check it. Could you setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with only the problem in it?

Comment: [link](http://pixelcrafts.com/dnahar/images/Untitled-1.jpg) here is a screen shot of my desktop,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to your `#menu-home>li>a` definition.